# Monitor has power but no display after water damage

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hardware-failure, water-damage

The story starts simple, I was just drinking some water when I accidentally flicked my bottle all over my 2nd monitor, water dripped down into the bottom of the screen when the settings menu kept opening and closing. It stopped and I thought it was all over. Suddenly, it goes black. It still has power but no display. I swipe my fingers across the buttons and to my shock, its dripping water. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.
You took too long to power it off. It shorted. Next will come the corrosion because you still haven't taken it apart to dry it properly.

Time for a new display; they're usually not worth the cost of repairing. You could try taking it to a technician, but as they might charge $£€ 60 just to diagnose it, that could have gone towards the price of a new display.